# Understanding linear vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**I** Which of the following sets are linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

1. $\{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_1 = a, a = \text{constant}\}$
2. $\{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_1 \ge 0\}$
3. $\{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_1 \cdot x_2 = 0\}$
4. $\{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_1 =0\} \cup \{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_2 =0\} $
5. $\{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_1 =0\} \cap \{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_2 =0\} $

My answers and thoughts:

1. **no**, because it has the form $\left(\begin{matrix} 2a \\ z_2 \\ z_3 \end{matrix} \right) \not\in \{x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)| x_1 = a, a = \text{constant}\}$
2. **yes**, it's like drawing an $n$-dimensional half-line
3. **not sure**, I think iif $(x_1 = 0) \oplus (x_2 = 0)$
4. **no**, if one of $(x_1,x_2)$ is $0$ in one of the sets, it won't be $0$ in the union
5. **yes**, because $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$

**II** Let there be the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$:

1. $T_1 = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^3 | a = (a_1,a_2,a_2), a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}$
2. $T_2 = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^3 | a = (a_1,a_2,a_3), a_1 \ge 0\}$
3. $T_3 = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^3 | a = (a_1,a_2,a_3), a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 0\}$

Which ones are linear subspaces?

My thoughts/answers:

1. **yes**, because given $u, v \in T_1$, it's always true that $ u + v \in T_1$ and $\lambda u \in T_1$
2. If I would follow the same train of thought as in **I (2)** above, I would say **yes** again, but this time I'm **unsure**, because it looks like the entire right-half of $\mathbb{R}$, if you imagine it in a cartesian system
3. I am inclined to say **yes**, because they are of the form $\left(\begin{matrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \\ -z_1 - z_2 \end{matrix} \right) \in T_3$, but I'm **unsure**, as I could express any dimensions in terms of the other two, in which case it's fragments of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose union is not linear at all

Please let me know which of my answers and thoughts are wrong, what their right answer are and the reasoning behind each. Thanks.

Comment: Note: I've learned this in German, so perhaps I haven't used the right mathematical terminology everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I

1. correct
2. not correct
3. yes: since $x_1 x_2 = 0$ if either $x_1 = 0$ or $x_2 = 0$ this is the same as 4.
4. yes: this is just the whole space.
5. yes: this is the $n-2$-dimensional subspace (since the first $2$ coordinates are zero)

II

1. correct
2. You can prove that it's closed with respect to $+$ and contains $0$ as well as inverses. Can you also prove that it's closed with respect to scalar multiplication?
3. yes! Draw a picture.

III

1. What do linear subspaces in $\mathbb R^3$ look like? For example, what do $1$-dimensional subspaces look like? And what do $2$-dimensional ones look like?

Hope this helps.

Comment: to II 1: the vectors have their y and z coordinates equal, they're both $a_2$

Comment: @Flavius Oh, right. I need glasses. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: To III: **1.** Do you mean a single point is also a linear subspace? This is insane! (but it sounds extremely consistent with the definition). **2.** lines, surfaces, and I guess you mean that rectangular parallelepipeds are also linear subspaces? What about generally parallelepipeds altogether?

Comment: @Flavius Can you be more specific about the point? Because for example, if the point is $(1,1,1)$ then $2 \cdot (1,1,1)$ is already not in the "subspace" (a subspace is also closed with respect to scalar multiplication!).

Comment: @Flavius Also: can you be more specific about what you mean by "surface"?

Comment: If "linear subspace" means subspace of a vector space, then I.2 and II.2 aren't subspaces.

Comment: @JavierBadia Yes, thank you for pointing it out. They aren't closed with respect to scalar multiplication. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @MattN. ignore the point stuff I've said, 1-dimensional is a line, I said a stupidity. By surface I meant a plane. What I don't get now is why the answer to **I 2** is **no**. Do the elements have to always go between $-\infty$ to $\infty$? To **II 2**: no, I can't prove that it's closed with respect to scalar multiplication, so the answer must be **no**. To **II 3**: how do I decide which dimension to express in terms of the others in such cases where an equation is given?

Comment: @Flavius: I think you are, if you will, thinking too much. You have a perfectly good defintion: Given a vector space $V$, a set $S \subset V$ is a subspace if $0 \in S$ and S is closed with respect to addition and scalar multiplication. Use that.

Comment: What Javier said : ) And yes to 1- and 2-dimensional subspaces. Though, the one point space consisting of $0$ is also a linear subspace.